# How do I stop re-directs to another website?

Tags: web-services

I created my own local website(to run in my localhost) called http://testrb.com. But when I key that in a browser, it is redirecting to someone else's https://www.testrb.com. I want to prevent this and view my testrb.com. How do I do this? I am using apache webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem cames from the browser: since third level domain "www." browsers now a days are trying to add that domain to the URL. To solve that try to type all the address adding also `http://`.

If still not working you should try to use a local DNS: add the alias in your `/etc/resolv.conf` to the line starting with `127.0.0.1` appending the domain name `testrb.com` separated with a space(in UNIX systems).